# What is difference between "d" attribute in the SVG's path data and android:pathData?

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, svg-android

I want to know the difference between "d" attribute in the SVG's path data and `android:pathData`. [Android developer site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html)
 says that

"Defines path data using exactly same format as "d" attribute in the SVG's path data. This is defined in the viewport space."

So I want to know can't we use this "d" attribute in the SVG's path data as `android:pathData`. If can't is there a way to convert that "d" attribute in the SVG's path data to `android:pathData`?

Comment: Your second paragraph from the developer site says they are the same. Why would you believe us and not that site?

Comment: @RobertLongson It says about the format. Not the whole path.

Comment: What's the difference? The format defines what you can put in the d attribute which seems to be what you're asking about.